# Passing only some subroutine arguments by reference in Perl

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference

I'm writing a subroutine that takes a number of arguments. Most of those arguments are the standard pass-by-value sort, where changes made to them within the subroutine don't matter outside of it. But one of them is an object (blessed reference) that I'd like to make changes to that are available outside of the subroutine, if it's passed in. If it's not passed in, I would like to instantiate it and treat it the same way as if it were passed in (but returning it in the end).

For example:

---

```
my $foo = Private::Foo->new();

# $foo->{'something'} eq 'old value'

Private::Foo->do_things('abc', 'xyz', $foo);

# $foo->{'something'} eq 'new value'

my $foo2 = Private::Foo->do_things('def');

# $foo2->{'something'} eq 'old value'
```

---

```
package Private::Foo;

# ...

sub do_things {
    my ($self, $arg1, $arg2, $foo) = @_;

    unless (defined $foo) {
         $foo = Private::Foo->new();
    }

    if ($arg1 eq 'abc') {
        $foo->{'something'} = 'new value';

        return;
    }

    return $foo;
}
```

---

I'd like to do this with as clean of syntax as possible, and I'm fine using any  features available in Perl v5.22 and higher. (I've tried to figure out how to do this using `refaliasing`, but it isn't very clean.)

What am I missing?

Comment: Re "*What am I missing?*", Nothing. Your code works as-is.

Comment: Re "*Most of those arguments are the standard pass-by-value sort*", Perl always passes by reference. For example, `perl -e'sub f { $_[0] = "def"; }   my $x = "abc"; f($x); CORE::say $x;'` outputs `def`.

Comment: Bah, you're right, this does appear to work. Some combination of things I was trying earlier were giving me errors; I guess they were unrelated. Also, what I was calling "pass by value" was the standard `my ($foo) = @_` that comes immediately at the start of the subroutine in my example (and not yours).

Comment: Copying the arguments after they've been received doesn't alter the fact that they were passed by reference. And the fact that you made a copy of an argument doesn't stop you from changing the argument.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, subroutine arguments are *always* passed by reference.

```
$ perl -e'sub f { $_[0] = "def"; }   my $x = "abc"; f($x); CORE::say $x;'
def
```

More importantly, your code does exactly what you asked already.

```
$ perl -e'
    {
        package Private::Foo;

        sub new { my $class = shift; bless({ something => "old_value" }, $class) }

        sub do_things {
            my ($self, $arg1, $arg2, $foo) = @_;

            unless (defined $foo) {
                 $foo = Private::Foo->new();
            }

            if ($arg1 eq "abc") {
                $foo->{something} = "new value";
                return;
            }

            return $foo;
        }
    }

    use feature qw( say );

    my $foo = Private::Foo->new();
    Private::Foo->do_things("abc", "xyz", $foo);
    say $foo->{something};

    my $foo2 = Private::Foo->do_things("def");
    say $foo2->{something};
'
new value
old_value
```

That said, you could clean up your method some:

```
sub do_things {
    my ($class, $arg1, $arg2, $foo) = @_;

    $foo //= $class->new();

    if ($arg1 eq 'abc') {
        $foo->{something} = 'new value';
    }

    return $foo;
}
```

It would be even better if you cleaned up your calling convention.

```
Private::Foo->do_something($arg1, $arg2, $foo);

my $foo2 = Private::Foo->do_something($arg1, $arg2);
```

makes far less sense than

```
$foo->do_something($arg1, $arg2);

( my $foo2 = Private::Foo->new )->do_something($arg1, $arg2);
```

Comment: Your cleaned up method returns `$foo` regardless of the value of `$arg1`, which is different from my example. Also, I left out that I had other code to run if `$foo` was undefined, so `//=` won't help me much here.

Comment: Re "*Your cleaned up method returns $foo regardless of the value of $arg1, which is different from my example.*", So what? I never said it was the same; I said it was cleaner.

Comment: Re "*I left out that I had other code to run if $foo was undefined*", You can check the number of arguments provided by checking the size of `@_`. That said, your calling convention was already overly complicated before you brought this up. Distinguishing absent parameters from undefined parameters is pushing things way too far.

Comment: Added simpler calling convention to answer.